# How could I identify a sentence disclosing some specific information in a paragraph?

Tags: nlp

For example, I have such a paragraph as below:
The first sentence (bold and italic) is what I hope to identify out. 
The identification goal includes: 
1. whether this paragraph contain such disclosure. 
2. what this disclosure is.

The possible problems are :
1. this sentence may not be in the begin of the text string. it could be in any place of the given paragraph.
2. this sentence may vary with words but with same meaning. For example, it could also be expressed as: "Sample provided for review" or "They sent to me an item for evaluation" or something like this.

So how could I identify such disclosures ? Anyone's idea would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

The paragraph:

***I was sent this Earbuds Audiophile headphones to review.*** I am just going to copy here the information from the site: "High Definition Stereo Earphones with microphone Equipped with two 9mm high fidelity drivers, unique sound performance, well-balanced bass, mids and trebble. Designed specially for those who enjoy classic music, rock music, pop music, or gaming with superb quality sound. Let COR3 be your in ear sports earbuds. Replaceable Back Caps, inline controller and mic
Extreme flexible tangle free flat TPE cable including inline controller with universal microphone. Play/Pause your music or Answer/Hang up a call with a touch of a button right next to your hands, feature available depending on your device capability. COR3 should be your best gaming earbuds.
Extremely Comfortable

Methods I have tried: 
Up to now, my processing is very naive: 1) humanly labeled 1000 pieces of reviews as a binary variable (1 represents including the disclosure text, 0 otherwise). 2) Collect all the disclosure texts as a corpus denoted by DisclosureCor; 3) Based on these DisclosureCor, I discovered some basic regular regression rules, like " review.* evaluation|test|opinion". 4) Using these summarized rules to label new data. 5) The problem is that rules may not be complete, since they are just my own subject summarizations. Besides,  theses rules may not only occur in the disclosure text, but also some other parts in the review paragraphs, thus generating lots of noises (i.e. low precision); 6) I tried to use classification based association rules to train some rules from the labeled data. As keywords number is huge, long long time is needed to train the rule, crashed often. 7) I also tried to compare the similarity the review paragraph with the DisclosureCorp, but it's difficult to find a threshold to cut whether a review paragraph contains disclosure.  These are all the efforts I have tried, could you please give me some hints ? Thanks.

Comment: If you must do true semantic analysis of the text, you're gonna need specialized NLP tools. W/o identifying a specific technology you're using and what you tried/considered with it, this is gonna be closed as way too broad.

Comment: Hi, thank you for the comments. I have been thinking about reediting the question to be more specific, but it seems not that easy.  Because I don't know a particular technology that I could use to solve this problem. Some methods I have tried are added in the question. Hope it could be more specific.